# How to find out what process I've created with nohup and kill it?

Tags: process, nohup

I ran this command:

```
nohup python3 crawler.py > out.txt
```

And I forgot to specify PID at the end of it!

Now how can I find out if it's actually running and how can I kill it?

Comment: You could `pgrep python3`, then `ps -fp#` replacing `#` with the PIDs returned by `pgrep`. Or, you could `ps -fu $USER | grep -E crawler | grep -E -v grep`.

Comment: @waltinator you basically provided a full answer but wrote it in the comments from where it could disappear any time. Please post answers as answers. :)